# Does the notion of "goes to" exists in mathematical logic?

Tags: limits, logic

I remember that I had a small confusion regarding a certain aspect of induction in the past and a professor of mine replied that when you prove something with induction, then *you do not prove for one after another, you prove it for all of them at once.*

Regarding this aspect, does the notion of *"goes to"* exists in logic? For example: When people teach calculus, they translate $h\to0$ as *"$h$ goes to $0$"* which gives me the idea that we walk step by step to the vincinity of $0$. But in analysis, we translate that notion as *"for all $h>0$"* which doesn't give me the same idea I mentioned previously.

Comment: Depends on what you mean. There is no intrinsic meaning to the words "goes to" out of context. Sometimes we use the term "approaches" rather than goes to, but both imply a process, as you say, of travel, when that is not actually what we meaning in most cases.

Comment: I think it would have to be a very strange context where $h\to 0$ can be formalized as "for all $h>0$". The latter does not even begin to involve the idea that some $h$s are _closer to_ $0$ than others (which seems to be inherent in writing $h\to 0$), but on the other hand it invents a limitation that $h$ must be positive, which is not usually implied by "$h\to 0$" -- on the contrary $h$ can approach $0$ either from above or from below. And even if you _can_ find such a context, it is certainly not as broad as "in analysis".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes. I should have said that it approaches zero from one side.

Comment: By the way, I like the statement about induction. Induction is the principle that takes us from *being able to prove it for one thing after another* to *knowing it for all inputs*.

Answer (score 2):

There is no formalization of "*goes to*" in mathematical logic.

Neither in Analysis there is such a formalization: the symbol $\text {lim}_{h→0}$ is an abbreviation for $∀ϵ>0 \ ∃δ>0$ that avoids any reference to "walking step by step to the vicinity of $0$".

---

The locution "*goes to*" is used for [*sequences*](https://books.google.it/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80) :

> agreeing that the expression “$\text {lim}_{n \to \infty} x_n = A$” is to mean that $A$ is the *limit* of the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ [the usual definition follows].
>
> If $\text {lim}_{n \to \infty} x_n = A$, we say that the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ *converges to* $A$ or *tends to* $A$ and write $x_n \to A$ as $n \to \infty$.

Similar for [*functions*](https://books.google.it/books?id=rxOoCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA106) :

> We shall say that the function $f : E \to \mathbb R$ *tends to*
> $A$ as $x$ *tends to* $a$, or that $A$ is the limit of $f$ as $x$ tends to $a$, if for every $ε > 0$ there exists $δ > 0$ such that...

But we have to note that this is only a *façon de parler*; we may simply say :

> the sequence $\{ x_n \}$ *converges* with limit $A$.

It can be misleading to "unpack" the symbol $\text {lim}_{x \to a}$ into its "components".

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer the core of my question. It only corrects a stupid mistake I made.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle - the title of your question is : "Does the notion of “goes to” exists in mathematical logic?" The final statement of my answer says : "Outside the context of Analysis [described in the answer], I do not think that we have a "more general" definition." But I will edit it :-)

Comment: I am interested in how the concept of *goes to* is formalized in mathematical logic. *Goes to* seems to tell me that we "walk along" the line and approach $0$ arbitrarily, but if I use "for all $h$, $|h|>0$", then this seems to lose the idea of *walking along the line*.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle - there is no formalization of it in math log. But to be "formal", neither in Analysis $\text {lim}_{h \to 0}$ is such a formalization. To say that $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta >0$ simply avoid the need of such a formalization.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is actually not very clear to me, but I'll assume that you're asking whether there is a way to **formalize** the notion of "as ... goes to ..." that occurs in analysis and that mathematicians happily manipulate in their heads with hardly a thought about quantifiers over $ε,δ$.

The answer is: **It is possible!**
$
\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}
\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}
$

Firstly we must stop thinking about the vanishing quantity as a single quantity but as a process in itself, which is captured by a sequence whose limit is zero. Borrowing [Little-o-notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_notation), we can more or less use the following translation:

> "as real $x \to 0$" $\mapsto$ "for every $x \in o(1)$"
>
> "$x \to c$" $\mapsto$ "$x \in c+o(1)$"

where "$o(1)$" is the set of real sequences with limit $0$, and "$c+o(1)$" is short-hand for pointwise addition of the constant sequence induced by "$c$" to each sequence in $o(1)$. Also define $seq(S)$ to be the set of sequences from $S$. For convenience, given any sequence $x$ and function $f$ we can define "$f(x)$" to be the result of pointwise application of $f$ to $x$.

One has to be very careful with the hidden quantifiers in the Landau notation! For example, continuity of a function $f$ on a domain $D$ is:

> $\forall x \in D\ ( \forall y \in seq(D) \cap (x+o(1))\ (f(y) \in f(x)+o_x(1)) )$

where the subscript in "$o_x(1)$" indicates that the constants depend on $x$. Uniform continuity of $f$ would be:

> $\forall x \in D\ ( \forall y \in seq(D) \cap (x+o(1))\ (f(y) \in f(x)+o(1)) )$

Or equivalently:

> $\forall x,y \in seq(D)\ ( x-y \in o(1) \to f(x)-f(y) \in o(1) )$

Notice the difference! For continuity the constant for "$o_x(1)$" comes **after** the "$\forall x \in D$", whereas for uniform continuity the constant for "$o(1)$" comes **before** the "$\forall x \in D$".